# How to JOIN two JSONs in environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, json, merge, jq

I have environment variable, which contains JSON text. I want to add some data to it with `jq` tool. I want to keep all old fields but add and/or overwrite new ones. The idea is the same as with adding paths to `PATH` variable, but with `JSON`.

Even I don't understand, how to make and example. For one value I wrote

```
echo "{\"A\":\"Hello world\"}" | jq -r
```

Now suppose I want to merge this object with another one

```
echo "{\"A\":\"Goodbye world\", \"B\": \"This was a joke\"}"
```

Comment: suppose this might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011086/merge-arrays-of-json

Comment: as well as this https://remysharp.com/drafts/jq-recipes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shell trick with process substitution to feed in the JSON string as a input file that is fed to `jq` and just concatenate the contents of the two files

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' \
    <(echo "{\"A\":\"Goodbye world\", \"B\": \"This was a joke\"}") \
        <(echo "{\"A\":\"Hello world\"}")
```

Since `A` is common key among the two objects, it is replaced in the final result

```
{
  "A": "Hello world",
  "B": "This was a joke"
}
```

Or you can use the input function

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' "{\"A\":\"Goodbye world\", \"B\": \"This was a joke\"}" \
                  "{\"A\":\"Hello world\"}" | \
    jq '.+= input'
```

[the `input` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#input) is for:

> `input` and inputs [...] read from the same sources (e.g., stdin, files named on the command-line) as jq itself. These two builtins, and jq’s own reading actions, can be interleaved with each other

Answer (score 1):

Your example is peculiar, because the new value would fully replace the old value.  The original value only has one key, "A", and the value to be "merged" contains a different value for key "A" which would replace the original.

So for the sake of illustration, I'll pretend that you meant these inputs to be in the other order (so that "Hello world" will overwrite "Goodbye world" and "This was a joke" will stay unchanged).

That can be done like so:

```
( echo "{\"A\":\"Goodbye world\", \"B\": \"This was a joke\"}" ; echo "{\"A\":\"Hello world\"}" ) | jq -s add
```

The crux of this is that you're just feeding in two json objects sequentially, so you use `-s` to make `jq` treat them as though they are in an array; and then you just pass them to the `add` filter which adds all of the elements of an array together.

When objects are added in `jq`, they are merged, with any identical keys being resolved in favor of the object on the right hand side of the addition operation (in this case, the latter of the two objects).

See documentation:

- [addition operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Addition:+)
- [`add` filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add)
- [`--slurp` option](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)

Comment: @Inian true, but I thought this would be less confusing given the number of curly braces and backslashes already present.  I had only a couple minutes to write it and didn’t want to go into shell syntax explanations.